# How to prevent my website from sql Injection? Struts

Tags: java, mysql, struts2, sql-injection

how to prevent my website from doing sql injection in it

I am working using Struts 2 , DB MY sql .

Answer (score 0):

The best way I think is to not re-invent the wheel and use the tools already available.  For a small project I would recommend to simply use prepared statements when querying your database.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

You could also look into using an ORM like Hybernate.  But make sure to use it as intended.  Even HQL can be susceptible to injection.  See: [how much safe from SQL-Injection if using hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596424/how-much-safe-from-sql-injection-if-using-hibernate)

The important thing is to not write your own native queries by concatenating query strings with values from untrusted sources.