# Prevent Sql Injection (Java)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sql-injection

I want to secure my application from SQL Injection attacks.

**First question**: What is better way to do it?

**The first method:** I convert every request to json here:

```
public JsonObject requestToJson(HttpServletRequest request) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{

        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
        String line = null;
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                jb.append(line);
        } catch (Exception e) { /*report an error*/ }

        return new JsonParser().parse(jb.toString()).getAsJsonObject();
    }
```

If it is best way, to prevent it here, then **second question:** how to do it here?

**The second method:** It can be done by Hibernate level. **Second question:** how to do it?

Comment: How would converting the request to JSON prevent SQL Injection? Why do you think HIbernate is vulnerable to SQL Injection?

Comment: no, converting to json is not preventing injection of course. I mean, as I'm converting every request to json, I can put this validation in this function.

Comment: I'm new in hibernate. I'm using several ways to generate SQL: JPARepository, CriteriaBuilder and HQL. My question is: "it's already preventing from SQL Injection"?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596424/how-much-safe-from-sql-injection-if-using-hibernate) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441193/are-sql-injection-attacks-possible-in-jpa).

Comment: Ok, about HQL, JpaRepository I understood. But what about CriteriaBuilder. Is it safe?

Comment: What *about* [CriteriaBuilder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065906/does-hibernate-criteria-api-completely-protect-from-sql-injection)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95402/discussion-between-annoirq-and-elliott-frisch).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks this user: **Elliott Frisch**. He answered in comment.

JPARepository like this already prevented from SQL Injection:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    User findByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber);
}
```

Just need to prevent if you using HQL:

```
String query1 = "select * from MyBean where id = "+ id;
String query2 = "select * from MyBean where id = :id";
```

Second one, will be secured.

Thanks, everyone.